# Can I set recipient of mailto to a php string?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, mailto

is it possible to set my mailto recipient to the $email string?
I have a reservation form on my website and i want to have 2 buttons(Accept/Decline) in the mail that i get from it. The buttons should automatically open a new email windows with the set body and the recipient email from the form. My problem is that i cant get the email from the form into the mailto button.

some help would be nice :)

```
 <?php
include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/mail.php';

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;


if($post){
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $amount = stripslashes($_POST['amount']);
    $date = stripslashes($_POST['date']);
    $time = stripslashes($_POST['time']);

    $message .= "Telefonnummer: ".$phone."\n<br />"."Personen: ".$amount."\n<br />"."Datum: ".$date."\n<br />"."Uhrzeit: ".$time."\n<br />";
    $message .= '<html><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><a href="mailto:<?php $email?>?Subject=Reservierung 73BB&Body=Hiermit bestaetigen wir Ihre Reservierung in der ...." target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #EB7035; border-top: 12px solid #EB7035; border-bottom: 12px solid #EB7035; border-right: 18px solid #EB7035; border-left: 18px solid #EB7035; display: inline-block;">Annehmen &rarr;</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></html>';
    $message .= '<html><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><a href="mailto:<?php $email?>?Subject=Reservierung 73&Body=Leider müssen wir Ihre Reservierung ablehnen da wir schon ausgebucht sind" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; background-color: #EB7035; border-top: 12px solid #EB7035; border-bottom: 12px solid #EB7035; border-right: 28px solid #EB7035; border-left: 18px solid #EB7035; display: inline-block;">Ablehnen &rarr;</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></html>';

$headers = "From: $name\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $mail = mail('tes@test.test', 'Reservierung', $message, $headers);

    if($mail){
        echo 'Ihre Reservierung wurde erfolgreich abgeschickt. Sie erhalten in kürze eine Bestätigung';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: *"is it possible to set my mailto recipient to the $email string?"* - Short answer: yes.

Comment: *"My problem is that i cant get the email from the form into the mailto button."* - What form? btw, you're sending as HTML, so you don't need the `\n`'s in the body. Those will literally show `\n`.

Comment: Sure, BUT: the `mailto` scheme is a huge pitfall, keep in mind that that requires support for that feature on the client side, which you do not know exists. So for example all users of simple web mailers won't be able to use such button at all!

Comment: a simple html form

Comment: If you want the email that has been input in the form: Use JavaScript. If you want email gathered from DataBase, echo it with PHP. I don't understand very well your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to open php tags again. Just add slashes and concatenate your variable.

```
$message .= '<html>...<a href="mailto:' . $email . '?...</html>';
```

Comment: Good! Have a nice day :)